# Looping over controller in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I wanted to know how I can return values from an ObjectController in ember. I know ember doesn't allow looping over objectcontrollers, but I need information from my controller to be displayed in my template.

Here's the template in which I want the data :

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="summary"> 
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Total Expenses</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each model}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{name}}</td>
                    <td>{{expense}}</td>
                    <td>{{formattedDate date}}</td>
                </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

Here's the controller for this template :

```
App.SummaryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['expenses'],
    userExpense: function() {
       var userExpenseMap = {}
       var expenses = this.get('controllers.expenses');

       expenses.forEach(function(expense){

           if(userExpenseMap[expense.get('whoPaid')]){
               userExpenseMap[expense.get('whoPaid')] += expense.get('amount');
           }

           else{
               userExpenseMap[expense.get('whoPaid')] = expense.get('amount');   
           }
       });

       userExpenseList = []

       for(var key in userExpenseMap){

           var obj = {};

           obj.name = key;
           obj.expense = userExpenseMap[key];

           userExpenseList.push(obj);
       }

       // console.log(userExpenseList);

       return userExpenseList;
    }.property('controllers.expenses.@each.amount')   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate in any property of the controller, but it must be an array. So you can use in your template `{{#each userExpense}}`:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="summary"> 
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Total Expenses</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each userExpense}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{name}}</td>
                    <td>{{expense}}</td>
                    <td>{{formattedDate date}}</td>
                </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did after I posted my question, but it's not working.

Comment: Hey marcio thanks :) it works.. there was some issue with ember refreshing my page.. guess i didnt need help at all, but I really appreciate the quick reply! Thanks again